# How to use descriptors with attributes of instances?

Tags: python, oop

I read the docs and saw that descriptors had to be used with class attributes only. What would be an acceptable way of using them within instances of that class?

I.e.

```
class Attribute( object ):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print "GETTING"
    def __set__(self,obj,val):
        print "SETTING"

class MyClass( object ):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myname = Attribute( '' )

name = MyClass()
print name.myname
```

Comment: You should inject attribute into class __dict__ — self.__class__.__dict__["myname"] = Attribute(''). But it certainly not what you want to do, because any other instances of this class will see what've happened.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulate them via `obj`, the second argument to the [descriptor's methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors).

Comment: Sorry, could you be a little more specific?